# Loop through all elements of "body" tags using DOM

Tags: php, html, loops, dom

```
$html = file_get_contents("test.html");
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$body = $xpath->query('//body');
```

I want to loop through all elements of the body tag of a HTML file and print out the "style" attribute associated with these elements. How can I do this?

Comment: all elements that are direct children of the body element or the entire tree of elements below body?

Comment: I meant the entire tree of elements below body :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can take my [RecursiveDOMIterator](https://github.com/salathe/spl-examples/wiki/RecursiveDOMIterator) for this:

**Code (compacted)**

```
class RecursiveDOMIterator implements RecursiveIterator
{
    protected $_position;
    protected $_nodeList;
    public function __construct(DOMNode $domNode)
    {
        $this->_position = 0;
        $this->_nodeList = $domNode->childNodes;
    }
    public function getChildren() { return new self($this->current()); }
    public function key()         { return $this->_position; }
    public function next()        { $this->_position++; }
    public function rewind()      { $this->_position = 0; }
    public function valid()
    {
        return $this->_position < $this->_nodeList->length;
    }
    public function hasChildren()
    {
        return $this->current()->hasChildNodes();
    }
    public function current()
    {
        return $this->_nodeList->item($this->_position);
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431142/');

$dit = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDOMIterator($dom),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);

foreach($dit as $node) {
    if($node->nodeType === XML_ELEMENT_NODE && $node->hasAttribute('style')) {
        printf(
            'Element %s - Styles: %s%s',
            $node->nodeName,
            $node->getAttribute('style'),
            PHP_EOL
        );
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Element div - Styles: margin-top: 8px; height:24px;
Element div - Styles: margin-top: 8px; height:24px; display:none;
Element a - Styles: font-size: 200%; margin-left: 30px;
Element div - Styles: display:none
Element div - Styles: display:none
Element span - Styles: color:#FE7A15;font-size:140%
Element span - Styles: color:#FE7A15;font-size:140%
Element span - Styles: color:#FE7A15;font-size:140%
Element span - Styles: color:#E8272C;font-size:140%
Element span - Styles: color:#00AFEF;font-size:140%
Element span - Styles: color:#969696;font-size:140%
Element span - Styles: color:#46937D;font-size:140%
Element span - Styles: color:#C0D0DC;font-size:140%
Element span - Styles: color:#000;font-size:140%
Element span - Styles: color:#dd4814;font-size:140%
Element span - Styles: color:#9ce4fe;font-size:140%
Element span - Styles: color:#cf4d3f;font-size:140%
Element span - Styles: color:#f4f28d;font-size:140%
Element span - Styles: color:#0f3559;font-size:140%
Element span - Styles: color:#f2f2f2;font-size:140%
Element span - Styles: color:#037187;font-size:140%
Element span - Styles: color:#f1e7cc;font-size:140%
Element span - Styles: color:#e1cdae;font-size:140%
Element span - Styles: color:#a2d9f6;font-size:140%
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It's nice and brilliant, works exactly as I expect the result to come :)

Answer (score 8):

Another option would be to use XPath to only find elements descended from the `<body>` and having a `style` attribute, like:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431142/');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query('/html/body//*[@style]');

foreach($nodes as $node) {
    printf(
        'Element %s - Styles: %s%s',
        $node->nodeName,
        $node->getAttribute('style'),
        PHP_EOL
    );
}
```

The output is the same as in [Gordon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431142/loop-through-all-elements-of-body-tags-using-dom/4431560#4431560) and the only important line is the `$nodes = …` one.

Answer (score 0):

I did it recursively like this.  I'm not sure if its the most efficient way.  I tried the method on this web page and it worked fine.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$body = $xpath->query('//body')->item(0);

recursePrintStyles($body);

function recursePrintStyles($node)
{
    if ($node->nodeType !== XML_ELEMENT_NODE)
    {
        return;
    }

    echo $node->tagName;
    echo "\t";
    echo $node->getAttribute('style');
    echo "\n";

    foreach ($node->childNodes as $childNode)
    {
        recursePrintStyles($childNode);
    }
}
```