# Converting HTML to another syntax (LaTeX) with PHP

Tags: php, html, regex, dom, latex

I'm trying to do a custom HTML to LaTeX converter, which uses Wordpress posts as a source.

Basically, it needs to do some "replacing", like:

```
<h2>H2 Title</h2>
<p>Text text text</p>
<img src="/image.png" alt="Image ALT tag" \>
```

To this

```
   \begin{document}

   \section{H2 Title}

   Text text text

   \shorthandoff{=}
   \begin{figure}[H]
   \centering
   \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{./img/image.png}
   \caption{Image ALT tag}
   \end{figure}
   \shorthandon{=}

   \end{document}
```

Which approach should I use? Is there a HTML DOM parser <strike>that allows replacements like this</strike>? Or other suggestions?

Update: Is there any way to walk *properly* in HTML DOM tree in PHP? I tried RecursiveDOMIterator (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431142/loop-through-all-elements-of-body-tags-using-dom) but I can't get a successfull result.

Thanks.

Comment: have you look at: http://html2latex.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)? Specifically, the "How to traverse the DOM tree?" section in the [manual](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how complicated the structure of the HTML in your posts is, you could use regular expression-based replacements (if the markup is fairly simple, as in your example). If you want to replicate complex structures (nested elements) into LaTeX, then regex likely wouldn't work.

Comment: Even if it is possible to parse the subset of HTML necessary for Hazar's task using regular expressions, it is still not advisable. This would quickly become unwieldy when dealing with attributes and would not give the tree-like data structure necessary to construct the LaTeX document.